# TFS 2017 Build Definition Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When I try to open a Build Definition in TFS I am getting "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."  I tried opening another and the same thing.

All the Tasks are gone!!!

I shut down the browser - The same error.
Rebooted my machine - The same error.

All its saying is that "This definition doesn’t have any process parameters yet. You can create and use them to promote the most important settings in your process." I don't want to lose all my tasks in my builds or have I and I am just screwed?
Can the Definitions be restored separately from the code portion of the TFS Server?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with the Data base who store this data.
I suggest you take a look at this and check if everything is ok.

Comment: What is missing is the field to enter the Solution,  It should be like **\*sln.  How do I get that back?

Comment: What do you mean ? Please provide some pictures.